# C# PUT Endpoint receives null argument with HMACAuthentication

Tags: c#, .net, python-requests, hmac

I am trying to make a call from my Python client to my C#.NET api endpoint.

The following two code blocks **work correctly**:

```
# Python Client
endpoint = "http://localhost:12345/api/myController/hmacTestPut"
data = {"type": "my_type", "state": "my_state"}
headers = calc_hmac(...)
r = requests.put(url=endpoint, json=data, headers=headers)
```

---

```
// C# Endpoint
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/myController/hmacTestPut")]
//[HMACAuthentication]
public IHttpActionResult HMACTestPut(MyDTO obj)
{
    return Ok(obj)
}
```

**However**, when I include the `HMACAuthentication` attribute on the C# endpoint, the `MyDTO obj` is `null`.

---

Since the endpoint is hit in both scenarios, I believe my HMACAuthenticationAttribute is correct.

Including `[FromBody]` does not seem to have an effect either way.

Is there a reason why adding `HMACAuthentication` to an endpoint would stop the body content from being received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else runs into this issue, this problem was (obviously) HMAC related.

In my HMACAuthenticationAttribute, in my ComputeHash() function, which is where I calculate the hash for the body of the request (as in POST or PUT body).

What was breaking is below, where reading the HttpContent to a MemoryStream left the HttpContent of the request empty for the actual endpoint to read nothing:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
await httpContent.copyToAsync(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var content = ms.ToArray();
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(content)
```

The **solution** was to change how we read in the content of the HttpRequest:

```
var content = await httpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(content)
```

---

Full simplified function below, in hopes that it helps somebody.

```
private static async Task<byte[]> ComputeHash(HttpContent httpContent)
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = null;
        var content = await httpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (content.Length != 0)
        {
            hash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```